# How to match up cells based on a string

Tags: google-sheets-formula

If I've got two tables, each one with a name-value pairs as entries where the name represents an investment, and the entry represents a monetary amount. One list represents investment activity (negative values), and another represents sale activity (positive amounts):

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bitcoin | -100 | Bitcoin | 1000 |
| DogeCoin | -50 | Ethereum | 10000 |
| Ethereum | -100 |  |  |

How might I build a query to generate a table that represents a multiple gain, with entries where there have been sales activity:

| E | F |
| --- | --- |
| Bitcoin | 10.0 |
| Ethereum | 100.0 |

I'm not sure how to do the division with absolute values, but the main problem is, I can't get the rows to match up since the first table has `DogeCoin` in row 2, but the second table has `Ethereum` in row 2.

I was attempting to use this query to just try to see if I could get the right values printing out in the same row:

```
  QUERY(
    A:D,
    "SELECT A, B, D WHERE A IS NOT NULL GROUP BY A",
    1
  );
```

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I've provided the source table, as well as the desired resulting table. They were not formatted properly previously. Hopefully that is what you're asking for?

Comment: Yep! that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

to use `group by` you need at least one aggregation (count, sum, max, min, avg):

```
=QUERY(A:D,
 "SELECT A,B,D,count(D) 
  WHERE A IS NOT NULL 
  GROUP BY A,B,D", 1)
```

Comment: Thank you. My real question remains, how do I guarantee that columns B, and D refer to the same A, since they're not guaranteed to be on the same row.

Comment: @hahuang65 can you share a copy/sample of your sheet?